# On the indendence of two standard Normal random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, independence

Let $X$ be a standard Normal random variable. Let $Y$ be a random variable with $P(Y=-1)=P(Y=1)=1/2$ . Then I can show that $YX$ also follows Standard Normal distribution.

My question is: How to show that $YX$ and $X$ are NOT independent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=(|X|\le x)$ and $B=(|XY|\le x)$. If independent, $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.  However, $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$.

Comment: (And $P(B) \neq 1$.)

Comment: $XY$ has a standard normal distribution.  $P(B)=P(A)\lt 1$,